# BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\registeration::register()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert the data in database while using Laravel. I am getting the error

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\registeration::register()

While register.blade.php is my view and registeration is the name of my table. The controller name is RegisterationContoller and its code is given.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\registeration;

class RegisterationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // register view
        return view('register');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        registeration::register(Request::all());
        //
        return 'insert';
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The code of web.php is given and it works correctly, before I have checked as a test.

Comment: does `App\registeration` class has a method called `register()` ?

Comment: register is the name of my view file where I placed the html code of the form

Comment: and registeration is the name of the model and the table in database

Comment: `registeration::register(Request::all());` I'm talking about this code. according to this one your `registeration` must has a `register()` function.. does it?

Comment: and post your detailed error. for an example. 
`message -  Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::mana does not exist.`
`exception - BadMethodCallException`

Answer (score 0):

If your Model Class name is `registeration` and you are simply trying to insert data into database, using eloquent.

then you simply do this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    registeration::create($request->all());
}
```